# How to get the web page title from selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web, driver

Below is the code used for getting the actual title form the Driver opened browser.

```java
public class imsclass1 {
    WebDriver driver;
    String actualTitle;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        actualTitle = driver.get actualTitle();
        System.out.println("ActualTitle is +");
    }
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void Beforeclass() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    
    @AfterClass
    public void Afterclass() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Output gets displayed as
Actual Title is

What I want is "Web page title" displayed in the browser.
It needs to be get printed in my console.

Comment: change your syntax instead of get actualtitle use get titie I mention below 
actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

Answer (score 7):

To get the page title use `getTitle()` method of driver.

```
actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, what I think you're looking for is this

```java
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

 public class imsclass1 {

    static WebDriver driver;
    String actualTitle;

    @Test
    public void test() {
      driver.get("http://www.google.com");
       actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
       System.out.println("ActualTitle is " + actualTitle );
                     }
      @BeforeClass
      public static void Beforeclass() {
       driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       }
     @AfterClass
     public static void Afterclass() {
      driver.quit();
      }
}
```

How this works:

`Driver.get` goes to the page.

`Driver.getTitle` gets the title of the page.

`System.out.println("ActualTitle is " + actualTitle)` prints the string "ActualTitle is " + the variable to the console.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

Just change code as per following :

```java
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
System.out.println("ActualTitle is :" + actualTitle );
```

Above will print title in console.. You have not added variable in print which storing actual title value and also you using wrong method to get title so you are not getting title.