# Exception triggered in EventFiringWebDriver when debugging in PyCharm

Tags: python, selenium, debugging, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

Debugging `Selenium` script with  `EventFiringWebDriver` in **PyCharm**, cause exception to be logged:

```
 'WebDriver' object has no attribute '__len__'
```

It slows down IDE but do not break (stop) the script.

Here is full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.event_firing_webdriver import EventFiringWebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.events import AbstractEventListener


class ScreenshotListener(AbstractEventListener):
    def on_exception(self, exception, driver):
        print(exception)


driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
ef_driver = EventFiringWebDriver(driver, ScreenshotListener())
ef_driver.get('https://google.com/')
title = ef_driver.title
driver.quit()

assert "Google", title
```

When I run attached script in standard mode everything is OK.

But running with PyCharm Debug (here is output from beginning of Debug console):

```
C:\Pro\selenium-debug\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 59668 --file C:/Pro/selenium-debug/simple_test.py
```

I get those exceptions (every time when I call `ef_driver`):

```
'WebDriver' object has no attribute '__len__'
'WebDriver' object has no attribute '__len__'
```

It not stopping the script, it just cause debugger to be slow (it updates driver and focus is set to the browser).

Any idea why it is triggered and logged?

Bonus: Running debugging in console with `pdb` is OK, so this looks like strictly **PyCharm Debug** connected thing

Comment: Did you try commenting out more and more of the code from the end and rerunning to see what line the error is at?

Comment: According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533830/how-to-get-the-web-page-title-from-selenium-webdriver/29534110

To get the page title you need to use driver.getTitle() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like PyCharm debug checks if an object has a `__len__` attribute:

```py
elif hasattr(v, "__len__")
```

and the object `WebDriver` has no `__len__`.

A solution could be (from the link below) to warp with try\catch:

```py
try:
    if is_numeric_container(type_qualifier, typeName, v):
        xml_shape = ' shape="%s"' % make_valid_xml_value(str(v.shape))
    elif hasattr(v, "__len__") and not is_string(v):
        try:
            xml_shape = ' shape="%s"' % make_valid_xml_value("%s" % str(len(v)))
        except:
            pass
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Please check this track:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39954